# 'pod install' with cocoa pods doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

So I'm currently watching a tutorial on Skillshare where I'm told to quickly google how to install cocoa pods and run pod install. Now I'm here after 3 hours of endlessly scrolling trough endless articles with no result. Unluckily since I'm new to coding I also have no idea what I want achieved with cocoa pods. I've installed around 10 ruby named things into my terminal but nothing seems to work. I went on to write an article to Cocoa pod but they sent me here. Maybe worth mentioning: I'm on a Mac mini with M1 chip and here's the article I wrote to cocoa pods: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10909

Comment: "xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode" Did you install Xcode?

Comment: Yes I have Xcode 12.5.1 installed. The tutorial is actually for building an app via Xcode

Comment: Did you launched Xcode? Once launched, `Preferences/Locations/Command Line Tools` check that `Xcode 12.5.1` is selected.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by launch Xcode I don't see any Preferences to navigate to once Xcode is opened as an app

Comment: Launch XCode, in the menu bar, `Xcode/Preferences/`... `Preferences` being a basic menu in macOS apps...

Comment: Ok found it and have that done. What to do next?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Terminal
- Use the command `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Once that's completed you'll want to actually enable the pods in your project. So using the terminal navigate to the folder where your `.xcodeProj` file is.

- cd /someuserFolder/desktop/blah blah...
- *Hot tip, you can drag your project folder into the terminal window to put it in there, the important part is that you use `cd` before the destination.*

Once you're navigated to that folder, in terminal type `pod init` which should create a `PodFile` which is where you'd add your pods. Open your project and add your pods to the podfile. An example might look like this. Alternatively, you can open the podfile in your choice of text editor.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Typically you'll just add the one-liners and all that extra stuff isn't necessarily required so you can get away with something like `pod 'firebase-analytics',`. Finally the remaining step is to close xcode, in terminal type `pod install` (While you're still in your project directory) then open the project using the generated `.xcworkspace` file, NOT the `.xcodeProj` file.

Comment: Did all of the steps above but the `.xcworkspace` file hasn't been created. This is what the terminal would say: `[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html`

Comment: Check this out. You're on M1, so make terminal run on rosetta. Then go through all the steps again. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907#issuecomment-655870749

Comment: But it also only installed 1 gem in the beginning if that helps
`sinan@Sinans-Mac-mini ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.10.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.10.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 0 seconds
1 gem installed`